# configuring ipdb to change the meaning of "!"

Tags: ipython, ipdb

When I call `import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()`, I'm able to step through the program by entering just `n`, but if I have a variable named `n` that I want to inspect I have to type `!n` or `p n` ("print" n). This often messes me up. Is there a way to change the behavior such that `!` is on by default (i.e., it acts like a normal IPython prompt by default) and the debugging behavior is triggered by some other key combination? Or perhaps setting it up so that I can toggle between variable inspection mode and line-stepping mode without having to always include the `!` prefix?